# Ordering geom_col NOT by fill value

Tags: r, ggplot2, cumsum

Please resist your instinct to jump at defining factors level. I am trying to make a bar plot with text annotations. I'm using geom_col with a y value aesthetic, and I'm using geom_text with a separate dataframe where the value has been converted into a cumulative sum. The order matters here, I want to plot based on the same order in which cumulative sum is calculated.

Example

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

example_df <- data.frame(gender = c('M', 'F', 'F', 'M'), month = c('1', '1', '2', '2'), 
           value = c(10, 20, 30, 40), name = c('Jack', 'Kate', 'Nassrin', 'Malik'))
setDT(example_df)
text_df <- example_df[, .(value=cumsum(value), name=name), by='month']

ggplot(example_df) + geom_col(aes(x=month, y=value, fill=gender)) +
  geom_text(data=text_df, aes(x=month, y=value, label=name), vjust=1)
```

[image: example plot]

If you can see here, the left side is exactly what I want. Jack is labeled at 10 over the M color, Kate labeled 20 above that over the F color. The right side though is wrong. Nassrin is labeled at 30, but over the M color that is of height 40. This is because geom_col by default orders by fill, which is converted to a factor in alphabetic order. What I want here is for the left plot to be ordered M, F but the right one F, M. Is this possible? Or is my best solution to reorder my cumulative sum  (which would lead to a different plot than I intend).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `group` and `fill` separately. The order of stacking (i.e. the *position*) is controlled by `group`, and when you don't define that it gets set automatically (in this case the definition of `fill` is used). So:

```
ggplot(example_df) + 
  geom_col(aes(x=month, y=value, group = fct_rev(fct_inorder(name)), fill = gender)) +
  geom_text(data=text_df, aes(x=month, y=value, label=name), vjust=1)
```

[image]

Note that we can also let `ggplot` do the cumulative sums for us. Then we can use just the original data.frame, simplifying your plot to:

```
ggplot(example_df, aes(month, value, group = fct_rev(fct_inorder(name)),)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = gender)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = name), position = 'stack', vjust = 1)
```